# Straightforward explanation of Theil inequality statistic for curve fitting

Tags: curve-fitting, rms

I’ve come across a paper ([here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1748-9326/aaa512)) that uses a “Thiel inequality statistic” (pages 9 and 10 of the [supplementary information](https://iopscience.iop.org/1748-9326/13/1/015007/media/ERL_13_1_015007_suppdata.pdf)) to determine goodness of fit for a model with its training data. I was wondering if you might be able to point me towards a straightforward explanation of how it works, and how it could be used in this context?

They also use a simple root-mean square error, does the Thiel statistic add anything that RMSE doesn’t?

I'm sorry if this is a lame question, please do let me know if you need any other information for it to make sense.

Comment: nudge? Can anyone help me?